# Java Interface Implementation Problem

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, implementation

I have a little problem.

Class ll:

```
interface jj{
    public class ll implements gg{
    public static String j ="C:\\";
        //some code here
}
}
```

Class ggg:

```
interface gg{
public class ggg extends JFrame implements jj{
               //bunch of code + a textfield
        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(72, 120, 217, 20);
        textField.setColumns(10);
               //bunch of code
}
}
```

CLass aaa

```
public class aaa implements jj, gg {
    public aaa(){

//File chooser here + editing strin "j" from class "ll"
        File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();



        if(f!=null)
        {
            jj.ll.j = f.getPath(); 
                //And printing "j" string to the text field from ggg class
            gg.ggg.textField.setText(jj.ll.j);
        }
}
}
```

My problem is, that text field printing doesn't work. I tryed to System.out.println the jj.ll.j string to test if it has something. and yes it has and works how expected.

Comment: Are you sure you need classes within interfaces?

Comment: My advice is to not embed non-interface classes inside an interface.

Comment: I need to use j string in 3 others classes. it would be much easier if java mades a multi inheritance feature, but we have what we have.

Comment: @shevchuk, use inheritance only when there is a object graph with parent-child relationships between classes. You dont need inheritance to access the same object from 3 other classes.

Comment: is this intentionally being obfuscated beyond all meaning? This is one of the strangest ways of declaring "public constants" I've ever seen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't get the logic of making a class inside an interface.

If you need the j string in various classes, just declare it as a public static field in some class. Implementing an interface to get a constant is quite old fashioned. If you use Java 1.5+, do a static import.

Comment: I don't really get how to do a static import. Could you please give an example.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little surprised that the compiler lets you do that--but unless you are just curious, don't do this.

Just find another way.

Added complexity is never worth it.